# json_decode getting JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX on POST request

Tags: php, json, syntax, request, decode

So I'm stuck on this error for some hours - I'm sending a post request thought my Java app using Retrofit2

```
    @PATCH("import/{id}")
    Call<Import> patchImport(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers,
                           @Path("id") int id,
                           @Body Import import
    );
```

This Import Body is literally the json below

```
{
    "user_id" : "2",
    "watermeter" : "1234",
    "allowance" : "56",
    "picture" : "",
    "comment" : ""
}
```

and then json_decode() inside my web app and I can get all the variables right in this format, but if I change
`"watermeter" : "1234a"`, I get JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX, same with adding anything besides numbers to any other variable, so I can't really pass in string and I dont know why I tried to remove Byte Order Mark but I can't seem to find the correct answer to this problem.

Trying this in Postman Body - raw, I get the same error.

Comment: What is the PHP?  And what is `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Are you sure you had quotes around `1234a`? You'll get that error if you do it without quotes.

Comment: But you shouldn't be creating JSON by hand in the first place. Use a library function, such as `JSON.stringify()` in JavaScript, `json_encode()` in PHP, etc.

Comment: @AbraCadaver JSON body isn't put into `$_POST`.

Comment: _I'm sending a post request with json_ OK then you're not sending a POST request, what are you doing then?

Comment: Php v 7.3 and tried on 7.4, var_dump is <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>C:\Users\qwasyx0-ntb\Documents\Projekty\bakalarka\vodomery_laravel\app\Http\Controllers\Api\ImportodectuController.php: 83:</small>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
  <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
</pre>

Comment: Barmar - that is the thing, when I debug the java code there are no quotes, I thought that is the problem but when I try the same in Postman with quotes, I get the same result

Comment: AbraCadaver I have API and I send @POST request to my endpoint with Headers and Object import, which is literally a json like I posted in question